# Why is safe navigation better than using try in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm reading [this](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). What's the benefit of using this:

```
user&.address&.state
```

over

```
user.try(:address).try(:state)
```

I still don't get it.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### (1) `&.` is generally shorter than `try(...)`

Depending on the scenario, this can make your code more readable.

### (2) `&.` is standard Ruby, as opposed to `try`

The method `try` is not defined in a Ruby core library but rather in a Rails library. When you are not developing a RoR web app but instead are writing e.g. little helper scripts, this will get relevant pretty fast. 
(I prefer Ruby over Bash, for example.)

### (3) `&.` makes debugging easier

The safe traversal operator will throw an error if a nonexistent method is being invoked.

```
>> "s"&.glubsch
NoMethodError: undefined method `glubsch' for "s":String
```

Only on `nil` it will behave leniently:

```
>> nil&.glubsch
=> nil
```

The `try` method will always return `nil`.

```
>> "s".try(:glubsch)
=> nil
```

Note that this is the case with most recent versions of Ruby and Rails.

Now imagine a scenario where a method named `glubsch` exists. Then you decide to rename that method but forget to rename it in one place. (Sadly, that can happen with ruby...) With the safe traversal operator, you will notice the mistake almost immediately (as soon as that line of code is executed for the first time). The `try` method however will happily provide you with a `nil` and you will get a `nil` related error somewhere downstream in program execution. Figuring out where such a `nil` came from can be hard at times.

Failing fast and hard with `&.` makes debugging easier than blithely returning `nil` with `try`.

***EDIT:*** There is also the variant `try!` (with a bang) that behaves the same as `&.` in this regard. Use that if you don't like `&.`.

### (4) What if I don't care if a method is implemented or not?

That would be strange. Since that would be an unexpected way of programming, please make it explicit. For example by fleshing out the two cases (implemented or not) using `respond_to?` and branch off of that.

### (5) What about `try`'s block form?

Instead of a method name, a block can be passed to `try`. The block will be executed in the context of the receiver; and within the block there is no leniency applied. So with just a single method call, it will acutally behave the same as `&.`.

```
>> "s".try{ glubsch }
NameError: undefined local variable or method `glubsch' for "s":String
```

For more complex computations, you might prefer this block form over introducing lots of local variables. E.g. a chain of

```
foo.try{ glubsch.blam }.try{ bar }.to_s
```

would allow `foo` to be `nil` but require `foo.glubsch` to return a non-`nil` value. Then again, you can do the same with the safe traversal operator in a more concise fashion:

```
foo&.glubsch.blam&.bar.to_s
```

Using `try`'s block form for complex computations IMHO is a code smell, though, because it impedes readability. When you need to implement complex logic, introduce local variables with descriptive names and maybe use an `if` to branch off a `nil` case. Your code will be more maintainable.

HTH!

Comment: Here comes my non-constructive comment of the day: Thanks for not using `foo` as the default variable. `glubsch` is more fun.

Comment: Response is old but just a comment to mean, in the last point, the `try` version and the `&.` version doesn't behaves the same. Example when foo is `nil`: try version will result in `nil.to_s` whereas `&.` version will try to call `blam` on `nil` and raise a NoMethodError

Comment: Actually, the truely equal version with full ruby should be more like `foo&.yield_self { |foo| foo.glubsch.blam }&.bar.to_s` or more readable if it's ok to consider to react the same for false foo as for nil foor: `foo && foo.glubsch.blam&.bar.to_s`

Comment: The example is indeed wrong. Thank's for pointing that out, @firetonton. I'll leave it there as a reminder that complicated chains of method calls are a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 27):

### (6) Speed

Safe navigation is almost 4 times faster than using the try method from [activesupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport)

```
require 'active_support/all'
require 'benchmark'

foo = nil

puts Benchmark.measure { 10_000_000.times { foo.try(:lala) } }
puts Benchmark.measure { 10_000_000.times { foo&.lala } }
```

Output

```
  1.310000   0.000000   1.310000 (  1.311835)
  0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.353127)
```

Comment: It seems to be 3 times faster on my machine, but you forgot to bench the case when `foo` is actually not nil. So I wrote the following benchmark: https://gist.github.com/alchimere/1cd424ee8b093867a88d82026734c78c and for non-nil objects, `&.` seems to be **8 times faster** than `try`

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we should be comparing those two things, because they do something else.

Given this example `Person` class

```rb
class Person
  def name
    "John"
  end
end
```

#### try

`try` should be used if you're not sure whether the given method **exists** on the object or not.

```rb
person = Person.new
person.name        # => "John"
person.email       # => NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Person>
person.try(:email) # => nil
```

#### &.

Safe nagivation should be used if you're not sure if the object you're calling your method **on** is nil or not

```rb
person = nil
person.name  # => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
person&.name # => nil
```

#### You can't use them interchangeably

People often confuse those two methods, because you can use `try` instead of `&.`

```rb
person = nil
person.name       # => NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
person&.name      # => nil
person.try(:name) # => nil
```

But you cannot use `&.` instead of `try`

```rb
person = Person.new
person.name        # => "John"
person.email       # => NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Person>
person.try(:email) # => nil
person&.email      # NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Person>
```