# Ruby method 'try' with two conditions

Tags: ruby

I should check if my User exists and whether the user is an organizer or an admin. Those two columns are boolean in my table Users. How can I deal with it purely? This code works incorrectly:

```
 <% if current_user.try(:organizer?, :admin?) %>
```

If I use `or` for `if` statement, it works well.

```
<% if current_user.try(:organizer?) or current_user.try(:admin?) %>
```

Comment: <% if current_user.try(:organizer? or :admin?)%> 
I mean this

Comment: What is `current_user`? What is `try`?

Comment: What do you mean to "deal with it purely"?

Comment: @sawa: I think they meant "cleanly/neatly". In some languages these all are the same word (russian, for example)

Comment: I used `current_user`  from gem Devise, so `try` for identify if user exists and check if user admin or organizer. Sorry for weak English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use

```
<% if current_user.try(:organizer?) || current_user.try(:admin?) %>
```

if you do not need something like this a lot. If you often need permission checks you might want to look into a tool that supports you with this. `cancancan` or `pundit` comes to mind.

If you want to avoid those `ored` checks, and don't want to add *pundit* or thelikes to your stack, you could add another method to your user model:

```
def admin_or_operator?
  admin? || operator?
end
```

and then just use that. The feasibility of this approach of course depends on the number of different roles and combinations you need to check.

Also: if you often need to check for the presence of a user (the reason you actually need `try`) then you could consider using the *nil object pattern*.

```
def current_user
  find_actual_user || Guest.new
end
```

Where `Guest` would be an object that responds `false` to all those permission checks.

Also some guidelines:

- you should prefer `try!` over `try` and if you are on ruby 2.4+ you should use *safe navigation* instead of `try!` ([Why is safe navigation better than using try in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977721/why-is-safe-navigation-better-than-using-try-in-rails))
- you should prefer `||` over `or` (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or)

If you want to know more about the reasons for above recommendations you can check stackoverflow or google.

Comment: "you can check stackoverflow or google" - maybe suggest some keywords for the searches? Otherwise, it's kinda useless advice. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev feel free to propose an edit to my answer.  As the topic of those two recommendations is different than what was originally asked I did not want to go into detail. I trust people do some work on their own and come back with remaining questions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev here you go

Comment: @pascalbetz: much better!